# inherting a custom jar file in GWT not working

Tags: gwt

I have a simple custom jar , which i am trying to import in GWT,
I have also inherited a module of the jar , But it always complains about missing module.

refer to the screenhots , as you see  i added th module in my project gwt.xml ,
then the screenshot of the module itself,and the ErrorInfo class, which should be accessible now in the project , but its complaining.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: are the source files accessible/included inside the jar or available as separate jar and added to the project?

Comment: It looks like they aren't based on the last screenshot, since it says "Decompiled .class file". After verifying that you have the sources in that jar (or a separate sources jar _also_ on  the classpath), please share the full error log as text if you are still having issues.

Comment: ahh, you are right ,  sources were missing, fixed Now. Thanks !,